# Why isnt Mockito doThrow throwing an Exception in this case? zero interactions with mock

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermock

method I am testing (**the method setEventHubDataPayload throws JSONException and  JsonProcessingException**):

```
public class EventHubMapper {

//inits

public byte[] toEventDataJsonByteArray(UserRecord inbound) {
    EventHubDto ehDto = new EventHubDto();

    ehDto.setEventTypeVersion(inbound.getVersion());
    ehDto.setEventId(inbound.getNotificationId());

    JSONObject eventJson = new JSONObject(ehDto);

    try {
        eventJson.put("data", setEventHubDataPayload(ehDto, inbound));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        analytics.trackError(AnalyticsConstants.EventHub.JSON_MAPPING_ERROR, e.toString());
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        analytics.trackError(AnalyticsConstants.EventHub.JSON_PROCESSING_ERROR, e.toString());
    }

    return eventJson.toString().getBytes();
}

}
```

unit test code:

```
 @Test
public void toEventDataByteArray_JsonException() throws JSONException, JsonProcessingException {
    EventHubMapper ehmMock = Mockito.spy(eventHubMapper);

    doThrow(new JSONException("blah")).when(ehmMock).setEventHubDataPayload(any(), any());

    eventHubMapper.toEventDataJsonByteArray(setUpMockUserRecord());

    verify(analytics, times(1)).trackError( AnalyticsConstants.EventHub.JSON_MAPPING_ERROR, new JSONException("blah").toString());

}
```

I've tried using more specific matchers ... ex: any(EventHubDto.class) or any(UserRecord.class) and got the same result:

```
Wanted but not invoked:
analytics.trackError(
"EventHub_Publish_Error",
""
;
```

and also

```
Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

what is going on here?

Comment: You expect to call trackError with PUBLISH_ERROR and empty string. But you actually call it with JSON_MAPPING_ERROR and e.toString(). Does PUBLISH_ERROR  equals to JSON_MAPPING_ERROR  value ? And what is the value of e.toString()? is it empty string.

Comment: these were typos, i fixed them, still have same error, @noname if you look at the reason for failure, its not mentioning the parameters

Comment: You are doing the `doThrow` call on the `ehmMock` instance. Whereas the actual call of `setEventHubDataPayload` is happening on the `eventHubMapper` instance. So the mock `ehmMock` is not being used. Try doing `ehmMock.toEventDataJsonByteArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to call like below while testing.

```
   ehmMock.toEventDataJsonByteArray(setUpMockUserRecord());
```